# Texture issue when uploading obj in zip?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

A simple model in obj extension I have uploaded in zip on A360 and check on this link  https://dm.autodesk.io/. Texture of that model seems good but at when I have uploaded heavy scene into it only color material are visible not texture. Why this happening ?

Comment: Is there any error shown in the browser dev console while loading the heavy scene?

Comment: no, there is not any error showing while loading, scene has loading properly but texture not visible.

Comment: Is there no any warning, either?

Comment: No warning is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no warning and error message, it's hard to figure out what happened to your model. If you can provide a reproducible case demonstrating that, I will gladly pass it on to the development team for analysis. Those following items should be in the reproducible case:

1. A short exact description of what you are trying to achieve. The behavior you observe versus what you expect, and why this is a problem.
2. A complete yet minimal sample source model to run a test in.
3. A complete yet minimal Forge app that can be run and debugged with a
   simple procedure to analyze its behavior lives in the sample model.
4. Detailed step-by-step instructions for reproducing the issue, e.g.
   which element to pick, what command to launch etc.

If your reproducible case could not be posted here publicly, please send it to the `forge.help@autodesk.com` and **remove sensitive data or information before you send**.